# As an Admin and Sharepoint Owner I can see my Promoted links ok

Tags: 2013, promoted-links

As an Admin and Sharepoint Owner I can see my Promoted links ok, however, some of my wider team cannot see the promoted link tiles in their full colour(or with the background image) and are greyed out .... any idea why this should occur?

Comment: Is it a custom prompted list? or the default one in the home page!

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the promoted links, and the permissions of the images.
Or maybe the images are checked out to you.